# How to add new rows to Vega input data

Tags: transform, vega

Is there a Vega transform that would allow replacing a row in the input by multiple rows in the output?

In my particular use case I would like to transform the following input data

```json
[
    {"open": "2019-01-01", "close": "2021-10-11"},
    {"open": "2020-22-22", "close": null}
]
```

into the following output:

```json
[
    {"date": "2019-01-01", "type": "open"},
    {"date": "2021-10-11", "type": "close"},
    {"date": "2020-22-22", "type": "open"}
]
```

Note how the first row of input data is morphed into two rows in the output.

Here is a [stub](https://vega.github.io/editor/#/url/vega/N4IgJAzgxgFgpgWwIYgFwhgF0wBwqgegIDc4BzJAOjIEtMYBXAI0poHsDp5kTykSArJQBWENgDsQAGhAATONABONHJnaT0lLdJAB3GrPpoALAAZTM+DTJY0AZnMycSWbJriyaATNlJMKVABtUHEkBDg0EHccBkwdYiQAGwYFNGCQNhw4DRAAJlMARgBOAFpCsoKdKES2CAj0fNyCkoLTFsqAXylQTOzIxrbc3JKhqpq6tHEGRMSOgF0ZTEUkcQgAMzZFBDS5+Y6gA) in the Vega editor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Vega transform *[fold](https://vega.github.io/vega/docs/transforms/fold/)* can do that:

```
"transform": [
    {
      "type": "fold",
      "fields": ["open", "close"],
      "as": ["type", "date"]
    },
    {
      "type": "filter",
      "expr": "datum['date']"
    }
  ]
}
```

]

[View in Vega on-line editor](https://vega.github.io/editor/#/url/vega/N4IgJAzgxgFgpgWwIYgFwhgF0wBwqgegIDc4BzJAOjIEtMYBXAI0poHsDp5kTykSArJQBWENgDsQAGhAATONABONHJnaT0lLdJAB3GrPpoALAAZTM+DTJY0AZnMycSWbJriyaATNlJMKVABtUHEkBDg0EHccBkwdYiQAGwYFNGCQNhw4DRAAJlMARgBOAFpCsoKdKES2CAj0fNyCkoLTFsqAXylQTOzIxrbc3JKhqpq6tHEGRMSOgF0ZTEUkcQgAMzZFBDTQTABPLMiNxNkdNZo4E4g0jKzJGWraiIWQJGugkH3Dnz9nrt2DvUQOdEpg4IodHAAB44CHoXyYBgIQIAcgRcBRcxA8xxQA)

[image]

Comment: Also thanks for the screenshot. I did not realise the data viewer was there!